# GA query to return unique count number

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In Google Analytics I have set up set a custom dimension that contains a string of tags (`ga:dimension1`).

Data Example: `"tag1,tag2,tag3"`. I also use events.

I use [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) to test some custom reports. For `tag2` it is working like this:

- metrics: `ga:totalEvents`
- dimensions: `ga:dimension1`
- sort: `ga:totalEvents`
- filters: `ga:dimension1=~(tag2)`

I receive results like this:

```
Custom Dimension 1  | Total Events
tag2                | 2
tag1,tag2           | 1
tag3,tag1,tag2      | 4
```

Is there a solution to count these results in a GA query and to receive something like:

```
tag2 | 7
```

So I need a single number as result - the count of column Total Events in these rows.

Comment: Since you are looking for a metric you might consider using a custom metric along with custom dimension - this will automatically be added up and you can query  a single number even without specifying any dimension.

Comment: The problem is I must save multiple tags in a custom dimension. So, I solved to get the total events for a tag. The next step I try is to create a custom report that will show me total events for each tag. Have you any idea how it can be solved?

Comment: I use collective.googleanalytics and I have already the solution for extracting unique tags from custom dimension. But the problem is how to get the value for each tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you are going to be able to do is to either remove the dimension and just request ga:TotalEvents.

- metrics: `ga:totalEvents`
- sort: `ga:totalEvents`
- filters: `ga:dimension1=~(tag2)`

This will return

7

**Why**

The reason its not working like you want it to is you are requesting a column in the database ga:dimesion1 and ga:TotalEvents.  The system is going to return unique values for each of them.

There are apparently rows for

```
tag2                
tag1,tag2           
tag3,tag1,tag2
```

There could just as easily be `tag2,tag1` which is different from 
`tag1,tag2`

I hope this makes sense