# collective.googleanalytics report with filter containing tag

Tags: python, google-analytics, plone, google-analytics-api

I use collective.googleanalytics for a plone website and I try to create a custom report that contains a list of tags and totalEvents for each one.

I have:
`Table Rows Expression: python:[row, metric('ga:totalEvents', {'ga:dimension1': row})]`
where row is the name for my tag and it appear in first column of my custom report.

The problem is I save multiple tags in custom dimension `ga:dimension1`. So in my report using this setting I receive the correct number only for the case where I have a single tag in custom dimension, but 0 in case that  there are multiple tags in `ga:dimension1`.

I solved with Query Explorer a report and it seems I need a filter like `ga:dimension1=~(Computer)` to receive the correct number. (This question is related to: [GA query to return unique count number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776388/ga-query-to-return-unique-count-number)).

So, my question is how can I use `Table Rows Expression` field in collective.googleanalytics to define this value like `~(tag)`?

UPDATE: More details here: https://github.com/collective/collective.googleanalytics/issues/22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a limitation in *collective.googleanalytics* -- it only checks the equality relation:

```
python:[row, metric('ga:totalEvents', {'ga:dimension1': row})]
```

A hack is to bring all the data you need on the client and use JavaScript on the client side to filter the needed data.

Also, currently, *collective.googleranalytics* does not support `ga:dimension` at all. There [is a pull request implementing that](https://github.com/collective/collective.googleanalytics/pull/21) which is not merged yet.